# Spacing in parameter name on swift functions

Tags: ios, swift, function, parameters

I want to add a space between parameter names of a swift function. I want to achieve something like in the prepare for segue function provided by swift

`func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

That "for segue" parameter name that is used on the function call when you implement it.

Eg. I want to create a function `func saveReceipt(for customer:....)` then I want to call the function `saveReceipt(for customer:....)`

Comment: "*That "for segue" parameter name that is used on the function call when you implement it*" – no, it's called as `prepare(for: ...)`. `for` is the argument label, which is used at the call site, `segue` is the parameter name, which is used internally inside the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how parameters work sadly.

Take the example of the `prepareForSegue` func. It looks like this as a func:

```
override prepare(for segue: ...) {
```

However, if you were to call it, it would look like this:

```
prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, ...)
```

You can only ever have one parameter name for when you call a func.

**Edit**

To look at your example, you could have a func like this:

```
func saveReceipt(for customer: ...) {
```

And then call it like this:

```
saveReceipt(for: MyCustomerClass, ...)
```

Comment: Oh, ok, I got it, always I thought that "for segue" is the parameter name used on the call

Comment: @VicentiuPetreaca Yeah no, the "segue" label is strictly internal. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your example `for` is the argument label whereas `segue` is the parameter name.
This "can allow a function to be called in an expressive, sentence-like manner, while still providing a function body that is readable and clear in intent."
(see https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html)

That is, you use the argument label for the caller and the parameter name inside the function body.

In your second example your call `saveReceipt` using `saveReceipt(for: myCustomer)` (`myCustomer` is the variable holding your customer) and use `customer` as the parameter name inside the body.